# How to join multiple SQL tables without matching columns and different number of row

Tags: mysql

I was hoping someone could help or point me in the right direction, I’m pretty new to SQL queries having mainly focused on FE and have the following issue.

I have 4 tables I need to connect and pull information from each:

**Users, Squad, Games-played and Games.**

The current possible column matches through FKs are:

```
Users

id
```

```
Squads

id
Player
Users.id FK
```

```
Games played 

id
Squads.id FK
Games.id FK
```

```
Games

id
name
Games_played.id FK
```

I need to get Games.name from the Games table to the Squad table, Games_played is my middle point and I’m wonder how I can use it to get that information across.

I can pass Games.id through to Squads from it being the FK for Games_played.

Games.id corespondents with Games.name (the column I want),

Whilst Games and Squads have a different number of rows I wanted to display Games.name, which may repeat themselves on Squads.

Example desired output:

```
Users.id = 1 | Squads.Players = w | Games_played.Games.id = 1 | Games.name = x

Users.id = 2 | Squads.Players = y | Games_played.Games.id = 2 | Games.name = z

Users.id = 3 | Squads.Players = s | Games_played.Games.id = 1 | Games.name = x
```

**So Games_played.Games.id = 1 will always show Games.name = x**

Users.id passed to Squads via FK.

Player coming from Squads,

Games.id coming from Games but passed as FK to Games_played and able to join to Squads as Games_played.Games.I’d,

Games.name coming from Games and somehow attached to Squads.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result. I can't make heads or tails of the explanation.

Comment: The essential considerations almost always revolve around what each table represents, what is the nature and meaning of any relationships between tables, and what question you want answered.  You seem instead to be zooming in on lower-level details.

Comment: You've tagged two different RDBMS, which are you actually using?

Comment: Perhaps less talking and more showing? A, B, C, D is too abstract methinks

Comment: @Charlieface Sorry about the ambiguity, I’ve updated it with more data. Let me know if this helps

Comment: @Stu MySQL is the db

Comment: @TheImpaler edited, hopefully this helps

Comment: @JohnBollinger let me know if the edited version helps or if not. I realised the original post didn’t really contain much to go by.

Comment: Please, *please* do not create column names with periods (`.`) in them.  It requires extra quoting and is generally confusing.  There are plenty of alternatives, such as using underscores (`_`) instead.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the `Users` table doesn't actually factor in to the question?  You don't appear to need anything from it for this purpose.

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by "without matching columns"? You say you have foreign-key relationships with which to associate rows from the various tables, and all the FK values have to match values from the associated column on the other side of each such relationship.  In what other sense do you think "matching columns" might be relevant?

Comment: @JohnBollinger the . Was a typo on my end and I was rushing to edit the question, in my code I’ve used _ , thank you though!

Comment: @JohnBollinger the . Was a typo from my edit, I’ve used _ in my code

Comment: So with my Squads table and Games table I can get Games.name as there isn’t a direct column Matt between them. I’m pretty inexperienced so not sure what I’m missing to get Games.name across to my Squads table

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes. I only included the users table to give the full picture

Comment: It looks like `Games` and `Games_played` have mutual foreign keys.  What is the significance of this?  In particular, are you trying thereby to represent something that `Games_played.Games_id` couldn't do by itself?

Comment: @JohnBollinger so the end goal is when running a GET request on Squads I get a json object with all the squad fields, Games_played.Games_id and Games.name fields.

Comment: "*so the end goal is ...*" -- what does that have to do with the mutual foreign keys?

Comment: @JohnBollinger what I’m stuck with now is my query request to make this happen. I can join Games and Games_played with INNER JOIN and then I wanted to them get that new table across to Squads.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I want to be able to add just Games with out needing to add it to Games_played, having 2 tables seemed the easiest way to do this and then joining them with the FK

Comment: The question is not why you have separate tables.  It is why *each one* has a foreign key referencing the other.  Inasmuch as you say that you want to be able to add to `Games` without a corresponding row in `Games_played`, it is now clear that the extra FK is an error, as the existence of `Games.Games_played_id` will require a row in `Games_played` for every row in `Games`.  Just drop that column; it doesn't look like you need or want it.  `Games_played.Games_id` is sufficient by itself to represent the relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to get Games.name from the Games table to the Squad table

I guess you mean that you want a query that returns the contents of the `Squad` table, augmented by the `Games.name` of the associated `Game`.  From the available structure, the natural and only plausible alternative appears to be this:

```sql
select
  s.*,
  gp.Games_id,
  g.name
from
  Squads s
    left join Games_played gp on gp.Squads_id = s.id
    left join Games g on gp.Games_id = g.id
```

If you want to ignore squads that that don't have any associated `Games_played` then use ordinary inner `join`s instead of `left join`s.

> Whilst Games and Squads have a different number of rows I wanted to display Games.name, which may repeat themselves on Squads.

That's not inherently problematic, but note well that given your key structure, your result will have one row for every row of `Games_played`, plus (in the `left join` case) one row for every squad that is not associated with any `Games_played`.  The latter group will have NULL `Games_id` and `name`.  That may mean multiple rows for some squads, each with a different `Games_id` and possibly different `name`s.  It could also mean multiple rows for some `Games`, each with different `Squad` details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, John! I’ll be more clear with my questions in the future.